# Working of labelEncoder in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, categorical-data

Say I have the following input feature:

```
hotel_id = [1, 2, 3, 2, 3]
```

This is a categorical feature with numeric values. If I give it to the model as it is, the model will treat it as continuous variable, ie., 2 > 1.

If I apply `sklearn.labelEncoder()` then I will get:

```
hotel_id = [0, 1, 2, 1, 2]
```

So this encoded feature is considered as continuous or categorical?
If it is treated as continuous then whats the use of labelEncoder().

P.S. I know about one hot encoding. But there are around 100 hotel_ids so dont want to use it. 
Thanks

Answer (score 19):

The `LabelEncoder` is a way to encode class levels. In addition to the integer example you've included, consider the following example:

```
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
>>> le = LabelEncoder()
>>>
>>> train = ["paris", "paris", "tokyo", "amsterdam"]
>>> test = ["tokyo", "tokyo", "paris"]
>>> le.fit(train).transform(test)
array([2, 2, 1]...)
```

What the `LabelEncoder` allows us to do, then, is to assign ordinal levels to categorical data. **However**, what you've noted is correct: namely, the `[2, 2, 1]` is treated as numeric data. This is a good candidate for using the `OneHotEncoder` for dummy variables (which I know you said you were hoping not to use).

Note that the `LabelEncoder` must be used prior to one-hot encoding, as the `OneHotEncoder` cannot handle categorical data. Therefore, it is frequently used as pre-cursor to one-hot encoding.

Alternatively, it can encode your target into a usable array. If, for instance, `train` were your target for classification, you would need a `LabelEncoder` to use it as your y variable.

Comment: Great answer. I wonder if there is one combined LabelEncoder and OneHotEncoder?

Comment: In sklearn's latest version of OneHotEncoder, you no longer need to run the LabelEncoder step before running OneHotEncoder, even with categorical data. You can do this now, in one step as OneHotEncoder will first transform the categorical vars to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a classification model then the labels are treated as classes and the order is ignored. You don't need to onehot.

Comment: #simon What do you mean by 'labels'? The output of labelEncoder() ?  Yes I am running multiclass classification model. And I checked , the output of labelEncoder() is of type np.array() and individual element is integer.

Comment: Yes. The target variable are labels. A classifier will treat them as categories not ordered.

Comment: Thanks. If this is the case then things are very easy. But then, why do we need get_dummies() or OneHotEncoding()? As these 2 functions  do the same thing but increase dimensionality, we can always use labelEncoder() instead if it works the way you are saying.

Comment: "A classifier will treat them as categories not ordered." You cannot make this statement, in general. It depends on the classifier and the implementation of the classifier. For example, a scikit-learn DecisionTree classifier will absolutely treat these as numerical, not categorical.

Comment: Getdummies and onehot are generally use for features not labels.

Comment: Pretty sure decision tree regressor treats it as numeric but decision tree classifier is unordered categories.

Answer (score 0):

A way to handle this problem is to change your numbers to label with package **inflect**

So I have been visiting all numbers of hotels id's and I have changed them into words for example 1 -> 'one' and 2 -> 'two' ... 99 -> 'ninety-nine'

```
import inflect
p = inflect.engine()

def toNominal(df,column):
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[index, column] =  p.number_to_words(df.loc[index, column])

toNominal(df, 'hotel_id')
```