# How to merge multiple dummy variables columns which were created from a single categorical variable into single column in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I am working on IPL dataset which has many categorical variables one such variable is toss_winner. I have created dummy variable for this and now I have 15 columns with binary values. I want to merge all these column into single column with numbers 0-14 each number representing IPL team.

[image: Screenshot of the dummy variables]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41773751/working-of-labelencoder-in-sklearn this should help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, Use:

```
df['Team No.'] = dummies.cumsum(axis=1).ne(1).sum(axis=1)
```

---

Example,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Toss winner': ['Chennai', 'Mumbai', 'Rajasthan', 'Banglore', 'Hyderabad']})
dummies = pd.get_dummies(df['Toss winner'])
df['Team No.'] = dummies.cumsum(axis=1).ne(1).sum(axis=1)
```

Result:

```
# print(dummies)
   Banglore  Chennai  Hyderabad  Mumbai  Rajasthan
0         0        1          0       0          0
1         0        0          0       1          0
2         0        0          0       0          1
3         1        0          0       0          0
4         0        0          1       0          0

# print (df)
  Toss winner  Team No.
0     Chennai         1
1      Mumbai         3
2   Rajasthan         4
3    Banglore         0
4   Hyderabad         2
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have one more doubt when I perform this I don't have to remove one variable to avoid dummy variable trap right?

Comment: @DilipKumar Can you explain more? What you meant by `dummy variable trap`?

Comment: That's a very useful tip!